# Как добавить доверенного юзера с правами рута в WHM?

Tags: centos, права

Здравствуйте. Мне приходят такие письма

> IMPORTANT: Do not ignore this email.This message is to inform you that the account root2 has user id 0 (root privs).This could mean that your system was compromised (OwN3D). To be safe you should verify that your system has not been compromised.

Я создал root2 справами рута. Как понял, что-то проверяет, на наличии рутовских юзеров и если находит добавляет в файле shadow перед паролем **!!**. Само собой после этого пароль уже не подходит, пока не уберешь эти самые **!!**.

Это всё хорошо, если объявится реальный злоумышленник. Но хотелось бы, что бы сама система знала, что это доверенный пользователь, а не взлом.

WHM 11.30.5CentOS 6

Если, кто знает, напишите пожалуйста (я c WHM плохо знаком и с CentOS, в основном работал с дебианом, а из панелек ispmanager).

Answer (score 1):

> Это всё хорошо, если объявится реальный злоумышленник. Но хотелось бы, что бы сама система знала, что это доверенный пользователь, а не взлом.

Хотелось бы, чтобы и ты догадался, что тебя хотят поиметь.